# Example that $\sum_{1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$ and $\sum_{1}^\infty g_{n}(x)$ are uniformly convergent but not $\sum_{1}^\infty f_n(x).g_n(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone give me an example that 2 series of functions $\sum_{1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$ and $\sum_{1}^\infty g_{n}(x)$ are uniformly convergent but the series $\sum_{1}^\infty f_n(x).g_n(x)$  is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: try to construct using characteristic function $\chi$

Comment: $f_n(x) = g_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n} + x^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(x)=g_n(x)=\frac {(-1)^{n} } {\sqrt n}$.

Comment: Can someone give an example where $\sum f_n(x)g_n(x)$ also converges but that convergence is not uniform?